# gPodder not recognising iPod classic

Tags: 13.10, sync, ipod, gpodder

In the past (on `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS`), I used `gPodder` without any problems to download and sync my podcasts with my `iPod classic`, however, now on `Ubuntu 13.10` and with `gPodder 3.5.1`, my iPod is simply not being recognised.

Ubuntu itself recognises the iPod (as does iTunes itself on the windows 8 boot).

What could be the problem? what things could I try to get gPodder to find my iPod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the help of `thp` I resolved this.

Turns out I need to install version `3.6.1`, which can be done from the `.deb` file [here](https://packages.debian.org/sid/gpodder).

This now made `ipod` reappear as a device option, and after a reinstall of `libgpod4` with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgpod4` my ability to sync with `ctrl+s` was restored.

I also found that to enable the system tray icon for gpodder on Ubuntu 13.10 I need to manually install `appindicator` by `sudo apt-get install python-appindicator`.

Finally, `gpodder --verbose` also gave the error `No module named eyed3` on my system, this can be resolved by changing `eyed3.mp3` to `eyeD3.mp3` everywhere in 
`/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/gpodder/sync.py`.

Now gpodder luanches without error and I can sync my ipod again!

The only thing that seems to be missing is the ability to `right-click` and sync a single podcast to ipod.

Answer (score 0):

I installed gpodder 3.8.3 (using this ppa: https://launchpad.net/~thp/+archive/ubuntu/gpodder), but I also needed to install python-gpod in order to get ipod syncing to work. 
Can't get album art to work, though.